# How can I set the Interactive Grid and its form in same page on Oracle Apex 18?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

I set the Interactive Grid and its form in same page. For exampe:

The name of table is TEAM, and it has columns like TEAM_ID, TEAM_NMAE, DESCRIPTION.

These contents are displayed in Interactive Grid, and they can't be edited in interactive grid alone.

I added Row Selector in Interactive Grid, set to select only one row at a time.

[image]

As you can see in above picture, below the page I set the form that displays contents from the seleted row in the interactive grid. I also added save, create, delete buttons in the form region.

So, I want to edit the table's contents in one page when clicking the button.

I can just display table's contents in items using '$s("P3_TEAM_ID", team_id);' function, but still, I can't apply changed items to real table (in the interactive grid).

In this case, how can I make the form and interactive grid work as I think?

Comment: You might have issues with the update depending on how you save the form data. What method are you using to save/update the data?

Answer (score 0):

Your gonna need to do some custom saving.

Display the data with some javascript $s

Then have a process that manually saves the page items into the DB.

```
UPDATE table
   SET name = :P1_NAME
      ,address = :P1_ADDRESS
    ...
  WHERE id = :P1_ID;
```

Something like that. Not that hard to do, just set it into processes when a save button is clicked.